# Ordering $2n$ numbers

Tags: combinatorics

In how many different ways can you order $2n$ different numbers with alternating $<,>$ signs?

An example for the case where $2n=6$ is 
$$1<3>2<6>4<5>1$$
$$1<5>3<6>2<4>1$$

Note that starting and ending numbers are same. Note also that the pattern of the signs are fixed as

$$a < \cdot> \cdots < \cdot > \cdots < \cdot > a$$

where $a\in\{1,2,\dots,n-1,n\}$.

Is there a group acting on $2n$ letters that preserves such 'pairwise' ordering?

Any group acting on with such constraints should have cardinality less than $|S_{2n}|=(2n)!$.

Comment: What do you mean by "group" and "ordering" in your last sentence?

Comment: @Cameron Buie Is it clear now?

Comment: Please clarify what characterizes a unique ordering.  For instance, are these two sequences equivalent?  $1 < 3 > 2 < 4$ and $4 > 2 < 3 > 1$?

Comment: Both are not what I look for. Ordering has to alternate.

Comment: A trivial observation, by partitioning the numbers into "high" and "low" partitions of the same size, by taking every odd position as an number from the "low" group, and every even position as a number from the "high" group, such an ordering is guaranteed.  Assuming that different starting numbers constitutes a "different" sequence, a lower bound is $(n!)^2$ (seen by permuting the "low" partition and permuting the "high" partition).  There are more than likely more than that however, or are there?  (something to think about).

Comment: @Turbo: True, but David still raises a point worth clarifying.

Comment: @CameronBuie They are distinct,

Comment: So are you asking for, given $n$, the number of sequences $a_0,a_1,a_2,...,a_{2n-1},a_{2n}=a_0$ where (1) $a_0,...,a_{2n-1}$ list each of $1,...,2n$, (2) $a_i < a_{i+1}$ for even $i < 2n$, and (3) $a_i > a_{i+1}$ for odd $i < 2n$? (For example, if $n=2$ then $2,3,1,4,2$ is legal, but $3,4,1,2,3$ is not.)

Comment: @JMoravitz:  I think there are definitely more than that.  You can divide the set of $2n$ numbers into $2$ subsets that do not overlap and where every integer in $S_2$ is greater than every in $S_1$.  So every int in $S_2$ is within < > and every in $S_1$ not, and they are both of size $n$.  This is what you describe and then of course there are $(n!)^2$ orderings.  But there is no rule that all in $S_2$ be greater than all in $S_1$ so there $must$ be more.

Comment: @miniparser hence why i posted as a comment instead of as an answer.  At the time I did not have a proof or counterexample worked for the claim so I left it as something to think about.  Further, the OP deleted his question shortly after so until now I was unaware that the question had been undeleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are very detailed answers on the web:
1) [Alternating permutations (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_permutation)
2) Richard Stanley, [A Survey of Alternating Permutations](http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/papers/altperm.pdf)

For the last part of the question - this is called *Foata group*, see some refs in Stanley's survey and this paper:
3) A. Kuznetsov, I. Pak, A. Postnikov, [Increasing trees and alternating permutations](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~pak/papers/IncreasingTrees.pdf).